# How can number of files in a directory affect Java memory mapped files performance?

Tags: java, nio, memory-mapped-files

While I was trying to do some performance test on number of files in a directory, and memory mapped files in Java, I encounter some strange results that I cannot explain. I ran this test on Windows 10, Java 8.

1. When adding 100, 1000, 10000 files in each directory, the results are very consistent. But when I store all 300,000 files in one directory, the results are 2-10 times slower. Well, that was what I want to test, so at least we can say putting too many files in one directory can affect the performance of memory mapped files. However, the swing is too much, depending on the order of running those buildFiles method.

2. Creating files using memory mapped files to write 4k data are faster than simply opening the files (the checkFiles method) without doing anything. That make no sense. One possible explanation could be the OS delay writing the metadata too.

I am hoping someone can run the test on a Linus box for me.

Please be check the data directory before you try to run the test, so it does not overwrite any of your data file. Calling the buildFiles method each time can also add 300,000 files to your disk, so make sure you have enough space.

```
package eval.files;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.MappedByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.nio.file.FileVisitResult;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.SimpleFileVisitor;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Random;

public class DirFileLimitTest {
    Path testDir = Paths.get("/AppData/"+getClass().getPackage().getName());
    int dataSize = 4096;
    byte[] data = new byte[dataSize];
    int totalFiles = 300_000;
    NumberFormat f = NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance();

    boolean memoryMap = true;

    public static void main(String...as) throws Exception {
        new DirFileLimitTest().runTest();
    }

    DirFileLimitTest() {
        new Random().nextBytes(data);
    }

    void runTest() throws Exception {
        clearDir(testDir, false);

        buildFiles(100);
//      buildFiles(1000);
//      buildFiles(10000);
        buildFiles(totalFiles);

        checkFiles(totalFiles);
//      checkFiles(10000);
//      checkFiles(1000);
        checkFiles(100);
    }

    void buildFiles(int maxChild) throws IOException {
        Path dir = testDir.resolve("child"+maxChild);
        ensureDir(dir);
        int[] levelFiles = computeLevelFiles(maxChild);

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for(int i=0; i<totalFiles; i++) {
            buildFile(dir, levelFiles, i);
        }
        System.out.println("buildFiles("+maxChild+"): 
        "+f.format(System.currentTimeMillis()-start));
    }

    void buildFile(Path root, int[] levelFiles, int fn) throws IOException {
        Path filePath = resolve(root, levelFiles, fn);
        ensureDir(filePath.getParent());

        FileChannel fileChannel = FileChannel.open(filePath,
                StandardOpenOption.READ, StandardOpenOption.WRITE,
                StandardOpenOption.CREATE);

        if(memoryMap) {
            MappedByteBuffer mem = 
               fileChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, dataSize);
            mem.put(data);
        }
        else
            fileChannel.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(data));
        fileChannel.close();
    }


    void checkFiles(int maxChild) throws IOException {
        Path dir = testDir.resolve("child"+maxChild);
        int[] levelFiles = computeLevelFiles(maxChild);

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for(int i=0; i<totalFiles; i++) {
            checkFile(dir, levelFiles, i);
        }
        System.out.println("checkFiles("+maxChild+"): 
            "+f.format(System.currentTimeMillis()-start));
    }

    void checkFile(Path root, int[] levelFiles, int fn) throws IOException {
        Path filePath = resolve(root, levelFiles, fn);

        FileChannel fileChannel = FileChannel.open(filePath,
                StandardOpenOption.READ, StandardOpenOption.WRITE,
                StandardOpenOption.CREATE);
        fileChannel.close();
    }

    int[] computeLevelFiles(int maxChild) {
        int levels = 1;
        int childCount = totalFiles;
        while(childCount > maxChild) {
            childCount = childCount / maxChild;
            levels++;
        }
        int[] levelFiles = new int[levels];
        int files = 1;
        for(int l=levels-1; l>=0; l--) {
            levelFiles[l] = files;
            files *= maxChild;
        }
        return levelFiles;
    }

    Path resolve(Path root, int[] levelFiles, int fn) {
        Path path = root;
        int remainder = fn;
        for(int level=0; level<levelFiles.length; level++) {
            path = 
               path.resolve(Integer.toString(remainder/levelFiles[level]));
            remainder = remainder % levelFiles[level];
        }
        return path;
    }

    public static void clearDir(Path dirPath, boolean deleteSelf) {
        try {
            Files.walkFileTree(dirPath, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
                @Override
                public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, 
BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
                    Files.delete(file);
                    return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
                }

                @Override
                public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory(Path dir, 
IOException exc) throws IOException {
                    if(dir != dirPath || deleteSelf)
                        Files.delete(dir);
                    return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
                }
            });
        } catch(IOException x) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot clear: "+dirPath, x);
        }
    }
    public static File ensureDir(Path dirPath) {
        File dir = dirPath.toFile();
        if(!dir.exists()) {
            if(!dir.mkdirs())
                throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot create directory: 
             "+dir);
        }
        else {
            if(dir.isFile())
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not a directory: "+dir);
        }
        return dir;
    }

}
```

Comment: You should use something like jmh for benchmarks, not just calling System.currentTimeMillis() (which isn't even guaranteed to produce a nondecreasing sequence of values; it will go backwards tonight in the U.S., for example).

Comment: You got me there, especially the time change this morning.  However, I just want to have a self contained simple class that can be run by anyone anywhere. The result is not that important, as it is affected by many external factors such as OS, RAM, disk type and format, etc.